# Xcode 8 Invalid code signing entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8, networkextension

I am creating an application that uses network-extension of iOS. The application is working fine also I am able to export IPA file. But when I try to upload it to testFlight this errors occurs:

[image: Testflight error]

I don't know whats going on. I have added network extension to provisioning-profile and appId. My entitlements:

[image: Entitlements]

Comment: post `error` in question instead of posting `screenshot`!

Comment: share your info.plist  ?

Comment: @KiranS it has "network-authentication" in "UIBackgroundModes"

Comment: based on the screeshot it seems. your bundle identifier in plist and provisioning profile bundle id doesn't match.

Comment: It seems you haven't correctly set up the entitlements for your AppID on the Apple developer website under your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was bug with Xcode. I recreated the whole project and everything was workign just fine.